# My phone toggles between on and off charge only when plugged into my MacBook Air

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, ios, battery, charging

Both my MacBook Air and the lightning cable are brand new. I've tried to clean the inside of the charging port of my iPhone 6s.

Comment: Having the same problem with 2015 MacBook Pro 17”.